# Rails nested form with radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

I have three related models

```
    class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :proposals,  :dependent => :destroy
    end

    class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :opportunity
    belongs_to :panel
    end

    class Panel < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :opportunity
    has_many :proposals
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :proposals
    end
```

I have a single opportunity and i want to list all proposals in a form, each having four radio buttons to assign each to a one of four panels.

```
    <%= form_for :proposal, :url => update_all_path, :html => { :method => :put } do %>
     <% @proposals.each do |prop| %>
      <%= fields_for "proposal[]", proposal do |proposal_fields| %>
       <%= proposal.name %><br>
        <%= proposal_fields.number_field :panel_id %><br>
      <% end %>
     <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

This form seems to work ok at the basic info. Ideally I want a series of radio buttons instead of a number_field or select.
So I would have:
Proposal A  -> 4 radio buttons**
Proposal B  -> 4 radio buttons**

For now I'd be happy just getting the new panel_id into the database correctly.

Here is the returned params

```
    "proposal"=>{"244"=>{"panel_id"=>"34"}, "245"=>{"panel_id"=>"33"}},
```

and my update method

```
    def update_all
      params['proposal'].keys.each do |id|
        @proposal = Proposal.find(id.to_i)
        @proposal.panel_id = params['proposal'][:id][panel_id]
      end
      redirect_to...
    end
```

and without further ado... the error

```
    NameError at /proposals/all 
    undefined local variable or method `panel_id' for #
    <ProposalsController:0x007ff3cf714420>
    Did you mean?  panel_url
```

How do i save the panel_id for each proposal ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: do you need `@panels.each do |panel| %>`  as collection_radio_buttons of @panels.all will give you 4 radio buttons for each proposal. please check

Comment: `<%= builder.collection_radio_buttons(prop, :panel_id, @panels.all, :id, :name ) %>` you should the first param prop